# JFXPanel resizing

Tags: javafx-2

I'm currently testing the integration of some JavaFX2 components in to a swing application.

I have a JFXPanel which contains an HBox Pane which holds a list of buttons. What I'm trying to achive is to hide and show some buttons and resize the HBox and the JFXPanel. Problems I'm facing:

1. When a  hide some buttons, the HBox does not resize itself.
2. I can modify HBox size (using resize method) but I must specify the
   dimensions (no automatic resize) the underlying JFXPanel does not
   resize. The autosize method does not seem to acomplish this either.

So, How can I resize it ? I'm using FXML and controllers so I see no easy way of resizing the JFXPanel but I'm trying to see how can I manually set it, but how can this be done automatically ?

By the way, I'm not using absolute positioning in swing (no layout manager).

Comment: Hi there, if my answer helped you & it was correct, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the button from the HBox, not just hide it.

I have done the same with a ToolBar & it update its size when buttons are added or removed.